# Fail to user ButterKnife in Android Studio and Android 5.0

Tags: android, butterknife

I user butterknife to develop my APP with android studio and test in android 4.4 and it perform well.

But when i test it in phone above android 5.0,it always throws error like below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for com.quinn.githubknife.ui.activity.MainActivity
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
        at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
        at com.quinn.githubknife.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)

 Caused by: ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'toolbar' with ID 2131689575 for field 'toolbar' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
            at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
            at com.quinn.githubknife.ui.activity.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:11)
            at com.quinn.githubknife.ui.activity.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:8)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
            at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
            at com.quinn.githubknife.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My core java code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainAuthView,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.nav_view)
    NavigationView navigationVIew;
    @Bind(R.id.viewpager)
    ViewPager viewpager;
    @Bind(R.id.tabs)
    TabLayout tab;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your activity_main.xml

Comment: This question cannot be properly answer if you don't provide the layout file...

Answer (score 1):

ButterKnife is unable to find `R.id.toolbar` for your annotated `Toolbar` view and throws a wobbly.  Either the view's id is wrong or it doesn't exist in `R.layout.activity_main`.  If you meant it to be optional, then you can add `@Nullable`.